# Wordpress woocommerce layout stying for cat page myaccount pages

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

Im trying to replace default header with my customized header.php for woocommerce and some parts of layout

I'm using custom child theme but that is inheriting header from 2023 layout home page and `taxonomy-product-cat` my custom header worked fine but for myaccount, cart pages this custom header is not applying and overwirting with 2023 header or it is coming from some where else i'm unable to locate(tried all ways)
this is style.css file

```
/*
Theme Name: childtheme
Author: author
Author URI: https://wordpress.org
Description: Twenty Twenty-Three is designed to take advantage of the new design tools introduced in WordPress 6.1. With a clean, blank base as a starting point, this default theme includes ten diverse style variations created by members of the WordPress community. Whether you want to build a complex or incredibly simple website, you can do it quickly and intuitively through the bundled styles or dive into creation and full customization yourself.
Requires at least: 6.1
Tested up to: 6.3
Requires PHP: 5.6
Version: 1.2
License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Text Domain:test
Tags: one-column, custom-colors, custom-menu, custom-logo, editor-style, featured-images, full-site-editing, block-patterns, rtl-language-support, sticky-post, threaded-comments, translation-ready, wide-blocks, block-styles, style-variations, accessibility-ready, blog, portfolio, news
*/
```

custome header(working fine wor home page and category pages)
[image]

this is cart and myaccount page header(default header loading)
[image]

I tried changes in form-login.php & cart.php files but header layout is not in that pages.